# Clean Firebase cache using glide

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, android-glide

Well im using firebase to store images related to the user profile, and something really weid is happening currently, i have a default image in my drawables that is displayed in a imageview that i have everytime my firebase storage ref is empty, else it will use glide to display the image, but i deleted all my storage at firebase and it stil show a image that i had in the database, why is that happening? is that related to the localStorage on the phone? how can i delete it?

```
    storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://friendlymanager-3b7a2.appspot.com/Photos/" + userId);


Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.esmad.pdm.friendlymanager/" + R.drawable.defaultuserimage);
Log.d("image2",storageRef + "/Photos/" + userId + ".jpg");
if(storageRef != null){
    Glide.with(this)
            .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
            .load(storageRef)
            .error(R.drawable.defaultuserimage)
            .into(userImage);
}
else{
    userImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.defaultuserimage);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try disabling use of both the disk and memory caches:

```
    Glide.with(this)
            .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
            .load(storageRef)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE) // <= ADDED
            .skipMemoryCache(true) // <= ADDED
            .error(R.drawable.defaultuserimage)
            .into(userImage);
```

**Added:**

Testing `storageRef` for null cannot be used to determine if data is stored at that location.  You can only determine the presence of data at a location by trying to load either the data or its metadata.

Comment: just a question, this should be user for developing, but is not a good practice lead it like that right?

Comment: These settings cause Glide to always load from Firebase storage.  I'm going to update my answer for another possible problem.

Comment: well i want to have that cache, but i want to prevent that just in developing it works fine, can you just give me another tip? how can i know that my storage reference is empty?, since im doing this f(storageRef != null){ but it keeps entering my if even if i dont have anything in the storage :S

Comment: Bob, first thank you for your answer, as you know in our days we need fast data and be dependent of wifi is bad, thats why i want to use the cache, but when i use cache and upload a new foto and replace it at firebase everytime i enter my activity with that photo i mantains the foto before, sorry for the long message, but do you know a good way to solve this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Glide enough to help more.  The documentation describes [cache invalidation options](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Caching-and-Cache-Invalidation).  Its seems like you will need to track when a new image is uploaded and invalidate the cache at that time, or change the signature of the image to get the new image at the next load.

Comment: Damn, its fine thank you for my help, i just don't get it why firebase has soo less methods :(